# How to hide second row of spans in div with a toggle of v-show?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm quite confused how to work around this one.
[image]
Basically I want to hide the second row to any row proceeding the first row when user clicks the "Advanced Search". I've achieved in only hiding the full span of pills but I want it that only the first row remains shown and the other rows hidden. The pills aren't put in a grid col or row but only bunched up with a `<span>` and some margin & paddings. Anyone can guide me how to achieve this? Code goes as follows

```html
<v-row class='mx-2'>
    <v-col class='d-flex pt-2 mt-1'>
      <!-- MYTODO: Put Toggle v-show to hide/show the down pills -->
      <span style='align-self: center; margin-right: 14px' @click='isShowPills = !isShowPills'
            class='advance-search-toggle'>
                Advanced search ({{ searchFieldKeys.length }} results)
                <v-icon
                  size='24'
                  style='margin-left: 11px'
                >
                  {{ advanceSearchIcon }}
                </v-icon>
              </span>
      <div v-show='isShowPills'>
        <template v-for='field in searchFieldKeys'>
          <v-chip
            v-if='searchFields[field].value'
            :key='field'
            close
            color='#fff'
            pill
            text-color='#7B7B7B'
            class='searched-field mr-2 mt-2'
            @click:close='removeSearchCondition(field)'
          >
             <span>
               {{ searchFields[field].text }} : {{ searchFields[field].value | formatSearchVal }}
             </span>
          </v-chip>
        </template>
      </div>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
```

Data goes as follows:

```js
data(){
   return {
     isShowPills: true,
     ...otherData
   }
}
computed() {
   advanceSearchIcon() { // MYTODO
      return this.isShowPills ? 'mdi-chevron-down' : 'mdi-chevron-up';
    },
   ...other Computed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can splice your array of filters (searchFieldKeys) like 5 so only first row will be visible. And if user clicks on advanced search you can return the whole array.

Make a computed property for it. And use it instead of searchFieldKeys in your html.

```js
computed : {
    filteredArray() {  
      if (this.isShowPills) return this.searchFieldKeys
      else {
        const newArray = this.searchFieldKeys.splice(0,5)
        return newArray
      }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Problem is, it depends on the results. For an example it may render 4 results on the first row since one of the pills may have long text thus resulting to only 4 pills on the first row and the 5th pill would then be on the next line of row.

Comment: Again the easiest solution would splice it 0 to 4 then. I also thought about a silly solution. You can count the words of the pills that will come to first row and if char count is less than for example 250 you make it 5 else you make it 4. What I am trying to say is you can splice your array dynamically somehow.